# Bootstrap Navigation Bar Does Not Display In Php File

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to figure out why my bootstrap navbar wont display while other bootstrap class will.

So in my code this works fine. The button displays fine which is proof that bootstrap works:

**index.php**

```
<?php
    echo '<div class="btn btn-lg btn-success">Test Button</div>';
?>
```

But if I try to display the navbar on the same **index.php** it fails miserably and I don't get it. Any idea?

```
<?php
echo '<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                  <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
                  </div>
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                  </ul>
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </nav>';
?>
```

**EDIT**

```
<!-- bootstrap javascript, jquery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- bootstrap css stylesheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: not showing even in `inspect element`? i don't think this is PHP issue at all.maybe this is just a css issue

Comment: @Ghost: I'm getting invalid property values when inspecting element?

Comment: I pasted your code into a page of my own that uses Bootstrap menus, and it works fine. Any chance you have a customized install of Bootstrap that doesn't include menu styling? Or you don't have the required JS included?

Comment: Why are you echoing a huge chunk of html?

Comment: @GregSchmidt : I'm using the cdn. I'm going to update with file referencing.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone: Just for testing.

Comment: I think I may know why... But first, have you tried including everything in only *one* pair of PHP tags?  For e.g. `<?php echo 'select button'; echo 'navbar html'; ?>`

Comment: @GrahamS. : No. What do you mean?

Comment: Are you trying to display both the Test Button and the navigation bar at the same time?

Comment: @GrahamS. : No just the navbar. The Test button was a test to see if it would display.

Comment: @GrahamS.: And yes just tried what you've suggested. The button displays, the navbar still doesnt display properly.

Answer (score 0):

After doing research and intensively reading Bootstrap documentation and testing codes here in [W3School Online Editor](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_gs_container&stacked=h) I realized that I wasn't doing nothing wrong.

Since they've migrated to Bootstrap 4, they've dropped a lot of their old features such as Glyphicon and how navbar displays.